# Jacobson radical of a tensor product

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, tensor-products, p-adic-numbers, central-simple-algebras

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $A_1$, $A_2$ be $R$-algebras. Is there any general mean to compute the Jacobson radical of the tensor product $A_1\otimes_R A_2$ in terms of ${\rm Rad}(A_i )$, $i=1,2$?

I am mainly interested in the case where $R$ is the ring of integers of a $p$-adic field $F$ and the $A_i$'s are hereditary orders in some simple $F$-algebras.

Comment: If $L/K$ is a purely inseparable extension of fields, the radical of $L\otimes _KL$ is nonzero while that of $L$ is of course zero. This leaves little hope to find a general expression for the radical of a tensor product.

Comment: In general I think there is nothing useful known, but in some special situations we have $rad(A_1 \otimes_R A_2)=rad(A_1) \otimes_R A_2 + A_1 \otimes_R rad(A_2)$. For example when $A_i$ are finite dimensional over a seperable field R.

Comment: @Mare what do you call a separable field? a perfect field?

Comment: @YCor Yes, I meant perfect.